# Flattening of a list of lists of jagged numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is what's the most pythonic and time efficient way to flatten a list containing lists of JAGGED numpy arrays?

It is structured like this:

```
mylist = [list1, list2, list3, ...]

list1 = [nparr11, nparr12, nparr13, ...]

nparr11 = np.ones((3, 3, 3, 32)) #arbitrary shapes
nparr12 = np.ones((2, 300))
nparr13 = np.ones((512,))
...
```

Of course, a regular concat or vstack won't work.

After hours of researching this is what I came up with, it may help someone:

```
arr = np.asarray(mylist)
flat_arr = np.concatenate([d.ravel() for d in arr])
```

Now this list is flattened, whatever the Numpy arrays inside look like.

Comment: We can't run your code without `mylist`.

Comment: @timgeb I assume `mylist` is a plain Python list of Numpy arrays. But I don't understand why the OP wants to convert `mylist` to an array if they're just going to iterate over it in a list comprehension.

Comment: @PM2Ring well I would be interested in the content of that list because maybe then I would understand what "JAGGED" means or how it is relevant, the type being `list` is pretty safe to assume.

Comment: @timgeb Fair enough. Usually "jagged" or "ragged" in this context means the arrays are of different sizes. And that's why simple stacking won't work here. And why they are in a list, instead of being in an array.

Comment: @timgeb mylist contains arrays of different sizes, exactly as PM2Ring says. You can add anything in it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I forgot to add, that each jagged "array" is itself a list of arrays! I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to test without a complete, minimal, verifiable example, but is there a reason you can't just do `flat_arr = np.array([el for L in mylist for arr in L for el in arr.flat()])`?

Comment: I think this works! I'd be intrigued to find out which is faster, np or list comprehension. Hopefully, there's a vectorized version of this because the arrays I'm working with are on the order of 10^6.